# Insert a character between other two characters in Vim

Tags: regular-expression, vim

If I search for patterns in vim with regex, then want to insert something without changing what the regex matched, what do I do?
For example, in a file with

```
foo123
bar4567

12zw231xy
```

I want to insert a newline between every non-digit followed by a digit, resulting in a file like this:

```
foo
123
bar
4567

12zw
231xy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:%s/\(\D\)\(\d\)/\1\r\2/g
```

- `\(\)` are capture groups. What is captured in them is reproduced by `\1` and `\2`.
- `\D` is a non-digit, `\d` is a digit.
- `\r` becomes a newline character in Vim.

This gets simplified with [magic mode](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic) regex, enabled with `\v`:

```
:%s/\v(\D)(\d)/\1\r\2/g
```

Comment: The `\zs` and `\ze` anchors are really useful to avoid capturing groups in many cases such as this one. You can use them here to make a zero-width match in between the two characters: `:%s/\D\zs\ze\d/\r/g`. Or you can use only one of them, in which case you can use `&` on the right to repeat the whole match: `:%s/\D\ze\d/&\r/g` or conversely `:%s/\D\zs\d/\r&/g`. Without the capture groups, you don't need to resort to the `\v` mode anymore, all backslashes are before letters (so wouldn't change under "verymagic").

Comment: @filbranden Very nice, thanks for teaching us something new!